# bug with IEntity.toString()?

Tags: quickbooks-online

There seem to be a bug with calling .toString() on an entity created by createQueryEntity. If you use it in a query. It will have some garbage string "tring" in it.

```
IEntity queryEntity = (IEntity) GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Vendor.class);
queryEntity.toString();

Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

Vendor vendor = (Vendor) queryEntity ;

return select($(vendor))
    .where($(vendor.getMetaData().getLastUpdatedTime()).gte(start))
    .where($(vendor.isActive()).eq(false))
    .skip(1).take(1000)
    .generate();
```

This would result to something like "select tring.tring.* from ..." Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Apparently you can't call any methods on the queryEntity returned by createQueryEntity BEFORE calling select(). That means toString() or ((Vendor) queryEntity).isActive() shouldn't be called before select ($(vendor)).

The solution is to store the results of select($(vendor)) first before calling these methods.

Be careful when debugging because adding a watch expression will call toString() too.